# Deployment of webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have deployed a webpart on one web application, and it is working fine.

When I am activating that webpart on another web application it gives an error that it is not registered as safe.

How can I programmatically ensure that whenever it activates it automatically adds the `safecontrol` entry in the web.config?

Answer (score 1):

If your are deploying your feature through a solution package (.wsp) it should only be a matter of also installing and activating the solution on the new web application before activating the feature containing your webpart.

The installation of the .wsp should take care of the necessary safe control registrations